# Dictionary of Dictionary : TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode

Tags: python, robotframework

My objective here is to have a dictionary which contains string as keys and other dictionaries as values.

So I built the below code to iterate over all values.

However, I'm facing the error : `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode`.

```
*** Test Cases ***
...
:FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
\    ${elementDictionary}=    Create Dictionary
\    Set To Dictionary    ${elementDictionary}    k1    ${v1}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${elementDictionary}    k2    ${v2}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${elementDictionary}    k3    ${v3}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${elementsDictionary}    ${k}    ${elementDictionary}
END

:FOR    ${elementKey}    IN    @{elementsDictionary}
\    @{element}=    Get From Dictionary    ${elementsDictionary}    ${elementKey}
\    Browse Dictionary Value    @{element}
\    Log To Console      ----------------------
END

*** Keywords ***
Browse Dictionary Value
    [Arguments]    @{dictionary}
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{dictionary}
    \    ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${dictionary}    ${key}
    \    Log To Console    ${key}    
    \    Log To Console    ${value}
    END
```

The error occured at the line : `${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${dictionary}    ${key}`

Could you please help me? Thank you a lot.

**Solution**

Used `${element}` instead of `@{element}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get Dictionary Keys` for fetching dictionary keys and loop that list instead of `@{dictionary}` in that `Browse Dictionary Value` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But `Get Dictionary Keys` will give me only the keys, not keys and values correct?

Comment: Yes, but you're using the key in `${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${dictionary}    ${key}` to get the value...